# Trigonometric AP relation on sides of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

The sides of a triangle are in AP (Arithmetic Progression) and the greatest angle exceeds the least angle by $90$ degrees prove that the sides are proportional to $7^{\frac{1}{2}}+1$ , $7^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $7^{\frac{1}{2}}-1$.

I tried to use the following property "when the sides of a triangle are in AP then the $\cot$ of half the angles are also in AP" but I couldn't get anything please help.

Comment: Please proofread your post ("to think least" ??) and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: SL loney Triginometry

Comment: Ah, Ramanujan's textbook. The angles, by the way, are $x<90-2x<90+x$, so you get $$\cot(x/2)+\cot((90+x)/2)=2\cot(45-x)$$

Comment: Gerry Could you please elaborate this solution .

Comment: Let a, b and c be the longest, middle and shortest side respectively. So, (a, b, c) are proportional to (7.5 + 1, 7.5, 7.5 - 1). Which means a + c = 2 * b. The largest angle is 90 + x, the middle is 90 - 2x and the smallest is x. So a, b and c corresponds to 90 + x, 90 - 2x and x respectively. Hence, Gerry's formula.

Comment: No I got this but how will I find the answer from this

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b,c$ where $a>b>c\implies a+c=2b$

$$\frac a{\sin(90^\circ+x)}=\frac b{\sin(90^\circ-2x)}=\frac c{\sin x}=2R$$

$$\implies a=2R\cos x,b=2R\cos2x,c=2R\sin x$$

Using $\displaystyle a+c=2b,\cos x+\sin x=2\cos2x=2(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)$

As $\displaystyle90^\circ-2x>0, \cos2x>0$

and also $\displaystyle\cos x,\sin x>0\implies\cos x+\sin x>0$

cancelling $\displaystyle \cos x+\sin x,$ we get $\displaystyle\cos x-\sin x=\frac12$

Squaring we get, $\displaystyle1-\sin2x=\frac14\iff\sin2x=?$

$\displaystyle\implies\cos2x=+\sqrt{1-\sin^22x}=\frac{\sqrt7}4$

$\displaystyle\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos2x}2=\frac{4+\sqrt7}8=\left(\frac{\sqrt7+1}4\right)^2$

Find $\displaystyle\sin^2x$  and use $\cos x,\sin x>0$

Can you find the required ratio from here?