# What does AP mean in the context of triangle proofs?

Tags: notation, triangles

On a number of posts, [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084979), I have seen people state that a triangle is "in AP". Can someone explain what that abbreviation stands for in this context?

Comment: Arithmetic Progression is often abbreviated that way and is not ambiguous anywhere.

Comment: Arithmetic progession. Cite: I googled and found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883612/trigonometric-ap-relation-on-sides-of-a-triangle

Answer (score 0):

Here it means arithmetic progression, so if the sides are $a,b,c$ we have $a+d=b, b+d=c$ for some $d$.  You also see GP for geometric progrssion.

Comment: Does proving that a triangle is in AP or GP have any significant meaning? Can we use these definitions to prove other things about the triangles?

Comment: I don't know of one.